# Retrieve a specific property value asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous

I am developing a project on `Wpf` which connects to a `Sql` database using `EF`.

Right now I am retrieving the data asynchronously with a `Task` to prevent the UI from blocking. I do simply as follows:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ItemsSource = myObjectContext.Table01;
            });
```

Everything is working as expected so far.

My problem is that one of my tables in the database has a column of type `varbinary` which stores a picture. So, It takes too long to retrieve all the rows from the database and I cant see anything in my application until all the data is completely loaded.

I have realized that the problem is the picture, ie. If I remove the picture from the table the data is retrieved so much faster.

So I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve some specific properties of an object in `EF` **asynchronously**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `.Select(x=>new{x.someprop})`

Comment: To expound on @L.B's comment, you could first select the properties you want, besides the picture, and asynchronously select the picture (could be using  code like your example, but preferably with [EF6's support for async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx)).

Comment: @TimS. Yes, I got the idea :). I'll give it a try, thanks